# Format current date time to "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ" in Angular/Javascript/Typescript

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, date

Is there an easy way to format the date time in Angular/Typescript in "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"

I got the current date by doing

```
const currentDate = new Date().toLocaleDateString('What should I add here')
```

Can you please tell me what do I need to add here in the method to get in format of yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ

Comment: Have you read e.g. https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe? Also note there's a [`toISOString` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString).

Comment: `new Date().toISOString()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to achieve this:

1. The Angular way using `DatePipe`

In you component, you can inject `DatePipe` from `@angular/common` and call on the `transform` method to format date. Here is the [list](https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe#pre-defined-format-options) from Angular docs of options you can use to format date and time.

```js
import { DatePipe } from '@angular/common';

class AppComponent {
  constructor(private datePipe: DatePipe) {}

  someMethod() {
    const date = this.datePipe.transform(new Date(), 'yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ss.SSSZ');
  }
}
```

In the module, where you have defined this component, you need to provide `DatPipe` as `providers`

```js
@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule, FormsModule ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ],
  providers: [ DatePipe ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

2. Second way would be to use native `toISOString()` method

```js
const date = (new Date()).toISOString();
```